# Deprecated function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

What to use in Kotlin (Android developing) to get directory path if

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

gives me:

> 'getExternalStorageDirectory(): File!' is deprecated.

Deprecated in Java and I can't use it

Comment: Try this
  <application 
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
.......

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation it seems that is deprecated.

> getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type)
>
> This method was deprecated in API level 29. To improve user privacy,
>   direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When
>   an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this
>   method is no longer directly accessible to apps. Apps can continue to
>   access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to
>   alternatives such as Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore,
>   or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

You can use **Context** in order to obtain your local storage directory

```
Context.getExternalFilesDir();
```

Where the **Context** is obtained from `this.getContext();`

In order to access mess around your local storage you will need to do some modification to your **AndroidManifest**:

- `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
- `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`